# jQuery parse JSON to array

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON: `{"listProductName":{"0100M":"100 MOTOR","0101M":"101 MOTOR OC Auto"}}`

I want pass it to select, so I have:

```
for(var i in responseServer.listProductName)
            aResults.push([i, responseServer.listProductName [i]]);
```

But I have select with option value 1,2,3 ..., but I want 0100M, 0101M and go on. How can I do That?

Comment: Wh... ere do `1,2,3` come from, and how do they correlate to `0100M, 0101M`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery parseJson function...

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"listProductName":{"0100M":"100 MOTOR","0101M":"101 MOTOR OC Auto"}}' );
```

you can get all products in variable obj.listProductName

Visit : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

Pass your Json Object to get the key arrays

```
function GetKeys(jsOnObject) {
            var keys = [];
            for (var key in obj) {
                keys.push(key);
            }
            return keys;
        }
```